# Expressing "Every person has a season in which the person thrives" in another form

Tags: mathematics, paraphrasing

How do I express the sentence

"Every person has a season in which the person thrives"

in the form

"For every person there is a season ..."

without changing the intended meaning?

Mathematically, the second sentence would be written as

"For every person there is a season such that the person thrives in the season",

or,
formally,

"For every person *p* there is a season *s* such that *p* thrives in *s*".

Nevertheless, since I am not an English native speaker, out of curiosity, I wonder how could that sentence be written in plain English, rather than mathematical English?

Comment: If you have a Bible, look up Ecclesiastes chapter 3, verses 1 - 8.  This is literally the canonical form of the quotation you want.

Comment: @Jasper: Thanks. I guess I did not make myself clear enough. Please see the later edition :)

Comment: Not Ecclesiastes, but *Every dog has his day*. :-)

Comment: @TRomano: Pardon me? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Every+dog+has+its+day

Comment: Do you mean "season of the year" literally, as in summer, winter, spring, autumn, or figuratively? We have been assuming you meant figuratively, not literally.

Answer (score 2):

As the saying goes, every dog has his day. But it sounds too infomal. I think 
We can say every person has his/her day or every person is in his/her heyday one day.
I think the word season does not fit here. Maybe we can say every person has his/her day(s) in which he/she thrives.

Answer (score 1):

> For every person, there is a season in which they thrive.
>
> For every person, there is a season in which he or she thrives.

Also, it's beyond the scope of your question, but some will argue that you should not use *they* to refer to a singular noun (as I have above). This is a matter of debate, and if you're interested, you can read more here: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/06/he-or-she-versus-they/.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to avoid formal predication and if, by "plain English", you mean that you are looking for a casual way of saying it...

**Everyone has their heyday or Everyone has his|her heyday.**

(with the same caveat that nmar offered, about the use of *their* instead of the singular *his or her*). You can get around that contentious issue (at least among copy editors) with:

**We all have our heyday.**

Answer (score 0):

If the OP means "season" literally (e.g. some people have Seasonal Affective Disorder when the sun leaves in the winter), then it would be something like:

Every person has a season in which they feel at their most energetic.

or

Everyone has a season in which they feel at their best.

or

Everyone has a favorite season.